# SQL Server function for wild card search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Sample table :

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
------------------
C*         value1 
Chi*       Value2 
Chil*      value3
```

Now I need a function which can return the columnB value based on the input that has the closest or exact match in ColumnA.

For example:

- if my input is ‘Chile’ then it should return value3
- if my input is ‘China’ then it should return value2
- if my input is ‘Colombia’ then it should return value1

Comment: How is Colombia the closest match to value1?

Comment: @Paparazzi there is a value ‘C*’ in the table

Answer (score 3):

Not sargable, but is is functional.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50)='China'

Select Top 1 * 
 From  YourTable
 Where @S like Replace(ColumnA,'*','%')
 Order by len(ColumnA) Desc
```

**Returns**

```
ColumnA ColumnB
Chi*    value2
```